# Realising endomorphism algebras as monoid algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

The representation-finite blocks of group algebras are exactly the Brauer tree algebras. Aaron Chan and I recently generalized the class of Brauer tree algebras to a larger class called special gendo-Brauer tree algebras, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05965 for the definition as endomorphism rings of certain generators over Brauer tree algebras (*). Now I asked myself wheter this larger class of algebras somehow appears exactly as the representation-finite blocks of a certain class of algebra (maybe special monoid algebras) generalizing the situation for group algebras. 
A related question is the following: Given a group algebra $A$ and a generator $M$ of mod-A. When is $End_A(M)$ a monoid algebra? Note that this is never a group algebra, when $M$ is not projective.

(*) precise condition on the generator $M$ is that $M \cong A \oplus X$, where $X$ is a direct sum of non-projective modules being all in the $\Omega$-orbit of a simple module $S$, whose projective cover is uniserial and stable Hom's betweens the pairwise different summands of $X$ vanish. For $X=0$ one reobtains the Brauer tree algebras.

Comment: Not very much is known about representation-finite blocks of monoid algebras.  This is an interesting question.  In general, quivers with monomial relations and relations of the form u=v are semigroup algebras so you can get anything representation finite of this sort.  So, for example, take a connected quiver and make all paths of length 2 zero.  Then if this meets the well known criterion to be rerpesentation-finite, it is a block in a monoid algebra and the monoid is fairly tame since it has commuting idempotents and trivial maximal subgroups.

Comment: I believe it is a theorem of Gabriel and someone whose name is escaping me that every rep finite basic algebra has a multiplicative basis. So any connected representation finite algebra is morita equivalent to a block of a monoid algebra

Comment: You probably mean the work done in this paper : https://eudml.org/doc/143254 .

Comment: That's the paper.